# Mint nft on Rinkeby testnet, and can't see it on testnet opensea

Tags: nft, testnets, rinkeby, smart-contract-wallets, opensea

Yesterday I deployed this contract: 0x561110d50B4625DE6d5Fa14E0c35608555E934cc on rinkeby testnet

I mint 4 nft on this account: 0x749C89F7F6054C8CD4a982c93E3E05e996BD5C19
And everything was ok because i see my 4 nft on opensea testnet.

But after I mint 4 other nft from the same collection on this address: 0x7248D4293592e02038661a2a2446b62F13277114

And now last 4 nft not showing on opensea testnet, I can see it on etherscan and in my metamask wallet but noting it on opensea.

I deployed other test contracts:

0xbdFF3CF9BCE1d4B4fFb45eF7B071e6CE93A80A7f
0xEF60997f63783c106eF91aC123107AE50e2FF750
0x03E938f54D9f612b92Ea1fF542c24b8F641CaE0B

Same result every time.

I am trying to change blockchain and test on mactic mumbai testnet but again same result.

Help me please :)